# Iinherited fields value are not changed

Tags: java, oop

I'm not sure if these question is still appropriate to be asked as there could be an answer already. But i still dont understand the concept of inheritance when it comes to attributes in parent and child class relationship. Please note the example below.

```
class Animal{
    public int lifeSpan = 50;

    public String imAn(){
        return "I'm an Animal";
    }
}

class Elephant extends Animal{
   public int lifeSpan = 100;

   public String imAn(){
        return "I'm an Elephant";
    }
}

public class Test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Animal animal = new Elephant();
    System.out.println(animal.imAn()+" and i live around "+animal.lifeSpan+" years");  
  }
}
```

Answer would be : I'm an Elephant and i live around 50 years.

I do understand the virtual method invocation concept here, but what makes it not load the lifeSpan attribute of child class. Does this means the class attributes are not polymorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this means the class attributes are not polymorphic?

No, fields aren't polymorphic. You've actually got *two* fields in your `Elephant` class - one declared in `Animal` and one declared in `Elephant`, which *hides* the one in `Animal`. That's the problem. You should get rid of the declaration of `lifeSpan` in `Elephant`, and instead initialize the *one* remaining field in a constructor.

You should *also* get into the habit of making fields private - and final, where possible. Assuming you really want to have a method to describe the name (rather than a field, which would be more usual) I would write your code as:

```
class Animal {
    private final int lifeSpan;

    public Animal() {
        // Default to a life-span of 50
        this(50);
    }

    public Animal(int lifeSpan) {
        this.lifeSpan = lifeSpan;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return "Animal";
    }

    public int getLifeSpan() {
        return lifeSpan;
    }
}

class Elephant extends Animal {
    public Elephant() {
        // Give every elephant a life-span of 100.
        super(100);
    }

    @Override public String getName() {
        return "Elephant";
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Animal animal = new Elephant();
        System.out.printf("I am an %s and I live around %d years%n",
            animal.getName(), animal.getLifeSpan());
    }
}
```

Comment: I could see a better implementation of the problem above. Thank you for your explanation. But i completely feel the scope of the attribute is useless if its hidden. Im not sure but, java should provide a compile time error in such case. An i really appreciate the way you restricted the variable private final.

Comment: @KumarKailash: Why would it give a compile-time error - and *where*? Note that any code with an expression of type `Elephant` will use the field declared in `Elephant`, and any code with an expression of type `Animal` will use the field declared in `Animal`. Fundamentally, the problem is that you've got two fields but only one piece of information. There are times when it *might* make sense for two classes in a hierarchy to both have a field with the same name - but if your fields are private to start with (as I believe they should pretty much always be) it won't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. pretty much convincing. And yes i agree to the point that there is nothing wrong in having fields with same name in the hierarchy.